# Как перевести экранные координаты в мировые?

Tags: opengl

Как перевести экранные координаты (координаты курсора) в мировые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, вот так (см. комментарии):

```
// Converts Screen X Y coordinates into Ray in the world space
procedure TKMViewport.ScreenToWorld(X, Y: Integer; out ray: TKMVertex3Ray);
var
  m: TMatrix4;
  vEye, vDst: TKMVertex4;
begin
  // Берем точки ближней и дальней плоскости видимой области (фрустума)
  // Вычисляем положение курсора в координатах от -1 до +1 по XY и 0..1 по Z
  vEye := TKMVertex4.New(X / fFrameWidth * 2 - 1, 1 - Y / fFrameHeight * 2, 0, 1);
  vDst := TKMVertex4.New(X / fFrameWidth * 2 - 1, 1 - Y / fFrameHeight * 2, 1, 1);

  // Будем умножать на инвертированные матрицы Проекции и Вида
  m := fMatViewProj.Inverse;

  vEye := vEye * m;
  vDst := vDst * m;

  // Итого получаем луч в мировом пространстве
  ray.Start := TKMVertex3.New(vEye.X, vEye.Y, vEye.Z) / vEye.W;
  ray.Endpoint := TKMVertex3.New(vDst.X, vDst.Y, vDst.Z) / vDst.W;
end;
```

Что делать с лучем дальше - ваш решать. Обычно он используется для хит-теста.